# What is the purpose of the row_factory method of an sqlite3 Connection object?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Somehow the docs didn't make it too clear for me. I'm having trouble understanding the purpose of row_factory method of an sqlite3 Connection object.

Basically, could you explain the following snippet?

```
def connect_db():
    """Connects to the specific database."""
    rv = sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
    rv.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return rv
```

Answer (score 23):

The line of code assigning `sqlite3.Row` to the `row_factory` of connection creates what some people call a 'dictionary cursor', - instead of tuples it starts returning 'dictionary' rows after `fetchall` or `fetchone`.

The pretty standard example:

```
import sqlite3 as sqlite

conn = sqlite.connect('companies_db.sqlite')

with conn:
    conn.row_factory = sqlite.Row
    curs = conn.cursor()
    curs.execute("SELECT * FROM companies_table")
    rows = curs.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(f"{row['companyid']}, {row['name']}, {row['address']}.")
```

Comment: Why is it called a 'factory'? Not a term I am familiar with in computing / databases.

Comment: 'Factory' or 'Factory method' is a 'design pattern'. It's an object or a function spawning almost identical objects or functions with one or few unique parameters which are later applied to something (if it's a function) or used otherwise (if it's an object).

Answer (score 15):

From the [`sqlite3` docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.row_factory):

> You can change this attribute to a callable that accepts the cursor
>   and the original row as a tuple and will return the real result row.
>   This way, you can implement more advanced ways of returning results,
>   such as returning an object that can also access columns by name.

Further:

> If returning a tuple doesn’t suffice and you want name-based access to
>   columns, you should consider setting row_factory to the
>   highly-optimized `sqlite3.Row` type. `Row` provides both index-based
>   and case-insensitive name-based access to columns with almost no
>   memory overhead. It will probably be better than your own custom
>   dictionary-based approach or even a db_row based solution.

You can find the same sort of explanation in the [Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/sqlite3/#easy-querying).

So this line:

```
rv.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
```

Sets the `row_factory` to the callable `sqlite3.Row`, which converts the plain tuple into a more useful object.

So now, when you pull rows from your database, you won't get back a plain python `tuple`, but a special object that makes it easier to work with (e.g. allowing you to access columns using names whereas a plain tuple would make you use numbered indices).

Comment: I read the docs. But that didn't make it clear to me. Could you explain with the snippet as an example?

Comment: @VaishMK what isn't clear? The explanation is fairly straightforward, so you are going to have to elaborate on exactly what you don't understand.